# Sed - Replace last occurrence of match for each line

Tags: regex, sed

So I have the following file:

```
Carlton 3053
Carlton North 3054
Docklands 3008
East Melbourne 3002
Flemington 3031
Kensington 3031
Melbourne 3000
Melbourne 3004
North Melbourne 3051
St Kilda East 3183
```

I want to replace the last space just before the numbers with a hyphen, this is the closest I've got

```
cat file.txt | sed -r 's/\ /\-/g'
```

But this replaces all spaces with a -
I want the output to look like this:

```
Carlton-3053
Carlton North-3054
Docklands-3008
East Melbourne-3002
Flemington-3031
Kensington-3031
Melbourne-3000
Melbourne-3004
North Melbourne-3051
St Kilda East-3183
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that as you want to do just one replacement, `/g` is not necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ sed -r 's/ ([^ ]*)$/-\1/' file
Carlton-3053
Carlton North-3054
Docklands-3008
East Melbourne-3002
Flemington-3031
Kensington-3031
Melbourne-3000
Melbourne-3004
North Melbourne-3051
St Kilda East-3183
```

- `([^ ]*)$` catches space + "anything not being a space up to the end of line".
- `-\1` print hyphen + the catched "anything not being a space up to the end of line".

Answer (score 7):

You know how to replace the first space, right?

```
rev inputfile | sed 's/ /-/' | rev
```

Answer (score 6):

Your attempt was close.  You just needed to capture everything before the space and needed a backslash reference in the replacement.  Not sure why you escaped the space and hyphen, though.

```
sed -r 's/(.*) /\1-/g' inputfile
```

For your input, it produces:

```
Carlton-3053
Carlton North-3054
Docklands-3008
East Melbourne-3002
Flemington-3031
Kensington-3031
Melbourne-3000
Melbourne-3004
North Melbourne-3051
St Kilda East-3183
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` variation:

```
awk '{$NF="-"$NF;sub(/ -/,"-")}1' file
Carlton-3053
Carlton North-3054
Docklands-3008
East Melbourne-3002
Flemington-3031
Kensington-3031
Melbourne-3000
Melbourne-3004
North Melbourne-3051
St Kilda East-3183
```

Answer (score 0):

The following also works on OSX since `sed -r` is not available there:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) /\1-/' file_containing_your_text.txt
```