# how to replace a lasted special character in each row

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
cat test1
a a 1 a aa 1 1 111 bb b
a1b a 11 b b b
1 asd fdg 1 bb b
```

I wanna to replace the end "1" shows in each row with @, keep other data as the same.
my expect result

```
cat expected_result
a a 1 a aa 1 1 11@ bb b
a1b a 1@ b b b
1 asd fdg @ bb b
```

Could this condition solved by "sed"? I don't know how to select the last "1" in each row, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed - Replace last occurrence of match for each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862083/sed-replace-last-occurrence-of-match-for-each-line)

Comment: or [Replace last occurrence of a character in a field with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649114/replace-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-field-with-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `rev` and `awk` solution too here.

```
rev Input_file | awk '{sub(/1/,"@");print}' | rev
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a a 1 a aa 1 1 11@ bb b
a1b a 1@ b b b
1 asd fdg @ bb b
```

Comment: It really discourages me when someone puts a down vote without telling the reason though others are trying to upvote and encourage here.

Comment: @LiuWill, your welcome, glad that it helped you, keep sharing knowledge and keep asking questions, cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

#### Method 1:

`1([^1]*)$` matches the last `1` on the line and everything after:

```
$ sed -E 's/1([^1]*)$/@\1/' test1
a a 1 a aa 1 1 11@ bb b
a1b a 1@ b b b
1 asd fdg @ bb b
```

#### Method 2:

`(.*)1` matches everything on the line up to and including the last `1`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)1/\1@/' test1
a a 1 a aa 1 1 11@ bb b
a1b a 1@ b b b
1 asd fdg @ bb b
```

This works because sed's regular expressions are greedy (more precisely, leftmost-longest).  The leftmost-longest match of `(.*)1` will match from the beginning of the line through the last `1` on the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. `*` is greedy, tries to match as much as possible and `1/\1@/` will match the last occurrence of `1` of each line and replace with `@`. If there is something else like 'x' to match and replace the last occurrence with `y` then it should be `x/\1y/`

```
sed 's/\(.*\)1/\1@/' filename
```

Output:

```
a a 1 a aa 1 1 11@ bb b
a1b a 1@ b b b
1 asd fdg @ bb b
```

Answer (score 1):

1([^1]*$), will match the latest 1 and anything ahead.

```
sed -r 's/1([^1]*$)/@\1/' v1
cat test@
a a 1 a aa 1 1 11@ bb b
a1b a 1@ b b b
1 asd fdg @ bb b
```

cat v1

```
cat test1
a a 1 a aa 1 1 111 bb b
a1b a 11 b b b
1 asd fdg 1 bb b
```

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for your reminder. i just think it's simple, do not need write a complete answer.

Comment: Yes it is but you should mention that `-r` is specific to old versions of GNU sed and you should use `-E` for portability between GNU sed and OSX sed or just escape the parens and remove the option and then it'll work in any sed.

Comment: thanks @Ed Morton, i really do not know this details info. thanks a lot.